# Why Doesn't NSArray return NULL for nonexistent indexes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

The way I understand it one of the things special about Objective C is that you can send messages to NULL and it will just ignore them instead of crashing.

Why is it that NSArray doesn't just return a NULL object if the index requested is out of bounds instead of causing a NSRangeException?

What I would expect from Objective C and NSArray is the following.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Object 1", @"Object 2", @"Object 3", nil];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    NSString *string  = [array objectAtIndex:i];

    if (string) {
        NSLog(@"Object: %@",string);
    }
}
```

Allowing me to access indexes of the array with don't contain objects and simply returning NULL. Then I can check if the object exists. I can do this in other places such as checking if the object has been instantiated.

```
NSArray *array;

if (!array) {
    array = [NSArray array];
}
```

I realize this is a theory based question but I'm curious :)

Comment: Messaging nil is completely different than asking for an out-of-bounds index. I don't understand why you're trying to make a connection here.

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense. Accessing memory outside of what your program has allocated is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior shouldn't be something a program relies upon, instead, it should be something that the program strives to remove. Now, admittedly, NSArray is not an array, but it must follow the paradigm of an array for most situations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Messages to nil is a language level feature, not a framework API feature.

That `NSArray` (and other classes) throw an exception to indicate programmer error is a conscious design decision that was made when the API was designed (~1993).   As both Kevin and Richard indicate, `nil eats message` is not erroneous in anyway whereas `out of bounds` is very much a case of erroneous input.

Where would you draw the line?   Should `substringWithRange:` accept any old input?   How about `setObject:atIndex:`?

By making NSArray @throw on bounds exceptions for `indexOfObject:` it makes the API consistent;  *any index (or range) that is out of bound will `@throw`*.

Comment: Alright thanks for the explanation. Just the kinda of thing I needed. I'm a self taught programmer with no CS education so this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Sure -- there is a lot of subtlety to the API design.  In many cases, what seems like an odd decision makes a lot of sense when put into the larger context.   API design and language design are *hard* to do well!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `NSMutableDictionary` to accomplish what you're trying to do. Set the keys to be `NSNumber` indexes. Invoking `objectForKey` on a nonexistent key (out of our imaginary bounds or removed) will return nil.

Comment: Thanks, not looking specifically for a solution to make it work I have always had workarounds and I more proper ways of dealing with it. was just curious. Upvote for trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist though! lol

Comment: This relates to another fact, which is that you can't have a sparse array. An array returning nil in response to `-objectForKey:` suggests that the there's an empty place at that index, not the index itself is invalid. Note also that `[-NSDictionary objectForKey:]` @throws if the key is nil.

Comment: which also makes an NSMutableDictionary a good candidate for use as a sparse array if one is needed.