# Handling an Exception At Runtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, ipad, exception

In my iPhone app, I need to get some values from an array like so:

```
string1 = [array objectAtIndex:0];
string2 = [array objectAtIndex:1];
```

However, sometimes, the object won't exist in the array depending on the user data. When a line like this is called and the object doesn't exist my app crashes naturally with an out of bounds error.

So how can I get around this? How can I detect when that object doesn't exist and set the string accordingly?

E.g.
if object at index does exist, string = ...

else if object doesn't exist at index, string = ...

Comment: related: [Why doesn't NSArray return nil for nonexistent indexes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691839/why-doesnt-nsarray-return-null-for-nonexistent-indexes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSArray has a count property you can use to determine whether an index will be valid.

```
if(array.count < index)
{ string1 = [array objectAtIndex:index]; } 
else
{ string1 = @"Not found"; }
```

If you want this to be universal functionality, you can use categories to add it as a method to NSArray:

```
@interface NSArray()
- (NSString*) objectAtIndexWithCheck:(int) index;
@end

@implementation NSArray
-(NSString*) objectAtIndexWithCheck:(int) index
{
   if(self.count < index)
   { return [self objectAtIndex:index]; }
   else
   { return @"Not found"; }
}
@end
```

Comment: The index argument should be an `NSUInteger`, and the category is a bit limited with the return type `NSString`, but overall this is the answer.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use a string either, but since the question was in the context of strings and setting it to another string if the object wasn't there, it's what seemed most suitable here. Is there any special reason to use an `NSUInteger` (besides avoiding the use of negative indices)?

Comment: That's the type of `objectAtIndex:`'s parameter, as well as `count`'s return value. In theory (though not in real life, of course), an `NSArray` can hold up to `NSUIntegerMax` objects, and `NSUInteger` can hold bigger numbers than `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that there is no array element with that index number, or that the object at that location has been collected?  If the former, then simply compare your array index value to `array.count`.  Your mention of "out of bounds error" suggests that this is the scenario.

But if you mean the latter case then fix your bug -- an entry in an NSArray should never be an invalid address unless you've got a serious heap management bug, and there's no reliable way to recover from this with exception handling.